# Are both $\int_{B_1} g(x) dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} g(x) dx$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge 3$ and consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$g(x) =(1+|x|^2)^{-(n-2)/2}.$$

As (little part of my) homework, I need to estimate separately both
$$\int_{B_1} g(x) dx\quad\text{ and }\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} g(x) dx,$$
where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at $0$.

In particular, it is required to prove that those integrals are finite.

I argued this way:
$$\int_{B_1} g(x) dx \le m(B_1).$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} g(x) dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} |x|^{-(n-2)} dx$$
which does not converge since $n-2<n$.

On the contrary, many of my class mates argued in this way:
$$\int_{B_1} g(x) dx \le \int_{B_1} \|g\|_{\infty} dx =\|g\|_{\infty} m(B_1) <+\infty$$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} g(x) dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} \|g\|_{\infty} dx <+\infty.$$

I am a bit confused, could someone please help me in understanding who is wrong?

Comment: Your classmates are surely wrong. Their last integral  is not finite.

Comment: Maybe you could use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classmates’ estimate $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus B_1}g(x)\,dx\leq \int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus B_1}\|g\|_{\infty}\,dx$ is true, but almost always useless. This is finite if and only if $\|g\|_{\infty}=0$, which is not the case here (i.e their final step of $<\infty$ is wrong here).

Your reasoning is also blatantly wrong.

> On the other hand,
> \begin{align}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} g(x) dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1} |x|^{-(n-2)} dx
> \end{align}
> which does not converge since $n-2<n$.

So what if you have an upper bound which does not converge? You need a lower bound whose integral doesn’t converge. Fortuntely, here, you can get such a lower bound: there definitely exists a $c>0$ such that $g(x)\geq \frac{c}{|x|^{n-2}}$ for all $|x|\geq 1$. One way to argue is because the function $|x|^{n-2}g(x)$ has a limit of $1$ as $|x|\to\infty$, so if $|x|\geq R$ for some large $R$, you can guarantee that $|x|^{n-2}g(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ say, then in a compact region $1\leq |x|\leq R$, you can just use the extreme-value theorem to get a positive infimum. This is the more ‘robust’ way of establishing the lower bound.

For your concrete function, we have that if $|x|\geq 1$, then $1+|x|^2\leq |x|^2+|x|^2=2|x|^2$, and so $g(x)\geq \frac{1}{(2|x|^2)^{(n-2)/2}}=\frac{1}{2^{(n-2)/2}\cdot |x|^{n-2}}$.